# Precargar una consulta MySql con respecto al mes actual

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, stored-procedure

estoy buscando la manera de pre-cargar una consulta enorme a una página web.
Hasta ahora, me han dicho que pruebe 2 cosas, Ajax y procedimientos almacenados.
Por ahora, estoy probando lo segundo, sino, trataré con AJAX.

Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente...

Debo lograr consultar registros que sean del mes actual, esto no sería problema para mi, pero hay un enorme problema que el encargado no quiere solucionar... la columna date, se creó como varchar, y nunca la han querido corregir y tampoco lo haran por que ahora demanda un cambio de otras cosas, por lo que debo convertir un string, a fecha con la que pueda trabajar. Por lo que estaba haciendo esto:

```
//Varchar a convertir - "2021-06-25"
STR_TO_DATE(`fecha_emision`,'%Y-%m-%d') as FechaF
```

Y para poder consultar datos dentro del mes actual, he hecho esto:

```
SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(`fecha_emision`,'%Y-%m-%d') as FechaF 
FROM boletas 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`fecha_emision`,'%Y-%m') = 
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),"-",MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)),'%Y-%m')
```

Entonces, ahora lo que necesito, es convertir esta consulta a un procedimiento almacenado, y poder llamarlo durante la carga de una página web a una tabla html.
Estoy haciendo el procedimiento, y me arroja este error, y no se que problema tiene:

```
//Error: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'END' en la linea 9
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE buscarMesActual(IN rut_in VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT *, 
    STR_TO_DATE(`fecha_emision`,'%Y-%m-%d') as FechaF 
    FROM boletas 
    WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`fecha_emision`,'%Y-%m') = 
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),"-",MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)),'%Y-%m') 
    AND rut = rut_in
END $$
DELIMITER
```

Posteriormente quiero llamarlo, pasandole un rut (un ID), y poder ejecutarlo desde php y cargarlo en html.

Comment: Tienes que devolver el delimitador por defecto (que es el punto y coma) al final poniéndo esto: **`DELIMITER ;`** En cuanto a lo otro que comentas (que es el gran problrma aquí), convendría que elabores un plan de normalización de los datos, para pasar esa columna a DATETIME.

Comment: igual, no se porque pensas que un SP va a hacer mas rapida la consulta, cuando pareceria que le faltan indices....

Comment: conucerdo con @gbianchi, suena más a tema de índices

Comment: El esfuerzo para hacer el procedimiento es casi el mismo que te tomaría hacer un par de triggers que actualicen una columna nueva tipo fecha, con su respectivo índice. Normalmente agregar una columna no tendría que impactar el código existente.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo he mencionado más de una vez a quien está encargado de eso, pero no hay cambios desde hace meses... estoy forzado a usar la columna de ese modo.

Comment: @gbianchi revisaré dicha tabla, y si el indice esta aplicado, lo reaplicaré, quizás sea problema de indices como mencionas.

Comment: @Sal Si lo ves de ese modo, si, pero el encargado de esa tabla tiene desarrollos con el formato varchar, implica que tiene que cambiar trabajos de hace 4 o 5 meses, todo por el cambio de 1 tipo de dato, pero no lo hará, por más que lo solicite...

Comment: agrega indices: `ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX product_id_index (product_id)`

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso ese indice no esta en la consulta.. deberia tener un indice por rut y otro por la fecha, por lo menos...

Comment: @gbianchi es un ejemplo de como se agregan índices a tablas existentes... no es una respuesta. si lo fuese hubiera creado una respuesta...

Comment: @Excorpion, solo reitero que no tendrían que cambiar código; la columna existente y todo su código relacionado se quedan igual. Hablo de una columna adicional redundante.

Comment: Entonces yo trabajaria sobre esa columna extra, como la creo al buscarla en el proc ? @Sal

Comment: Olvida el procedimiento, los SP ayudan al desempeño en casos muy particulares, y no es tu caso. Ayudan más los índices, y las funciones normalmente invalidan los índices (exceptuando *índices funcionales*). ¿Usas MySQL 8?.

Comment: Es un servidor de hostgator, como se que version mysql usa ?

Comment: @Excorpion `show variables like 'version';`

Comment: @Sal version
5.7.23-23

Answer (score 0):

La propuesta es usar una columna redundante:

```
ALTER TABLE boletas
  ADD fecha_emi DATE AFTER fecha_emision
, ADD index femi(fecha_emi);
```

Estos triggers asignarán automáticamente el valor de la nueva columna:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bol_bi BEFORE INSERT ON boletas
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.fecha_emi = str_to_date(NEW.fecha_emision,'%Y-%m-%d');

CREATE TRIGGER bol_bu BEFORE UPDATE ON boletas
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.fecha_emi = str_to_date(NEW.fecha_emision,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

Para iniciar el valor con los datos actuales simplemente hay que detonar el gatillo:

```
UPDATE boletas SET fecha_emi = null;
```

Con lo anterior ésta consulta tomará el índice sobre la columna nueva:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM boletas
  WHERE fecha_emi between curdate()-interval day(curdate())-1 day
                      and last_day(curdate());
```

Con esto consigues una base sólida para nuevos desarrollos.
Puedes cambiar paulatinamente el código que usa el VARCHAR por el DATE.
El caso a priorizar es donde tengas -si hay- inserciones sin columnas nombradas, es decir: `INSERT boletas VALUES(...)` donde deberán hacer algún cambio.